# How to Correctly Write the Wasserstein (Kantorovich) Distance between Transition Probability Densities of two Markov Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, optimal-transport, wasserstein

I am exploring an idea which is based on computing the Wasserstein (Kantorovich) distance between the empirical transition probability densities of two Itô diffusion processes.

Following from [this paper by A. Milian](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3214570?seq=2), the transition probability of the process $X(t)$

$$P(t,x,s,y) = Pr \left[ X(s) \le y | X(t) = x \right], t<s$$

has the density function $p(t,x,s,y)$.

In this problem I am working on I consider a pair of processes, $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$. Let the transition density function of $X(t)$ be $p(t,x,s,y)$ and of $Y(t)$ be $q(t,x,s,y)$. And I wish to write out an expression for the Wasserstein (Kantorvich) distance between $p(t,x,s,y)$ and $q(t,x,s,y)$.

First we should define the Wasserstein-p distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a metric space $M$ as

$$W_p (\mu, \nu)= \left( \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma (\mu, \nu)} \mathbb{E}_{ (x,y)\sim \gamma } d(x, y)^p \right)^{1/p}$$

where $\Gamma(\mu, \nu)$ is the set of couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$. The gap that I am trying to bridge here, and write out correctly is that we consider $p(t,x,s,y)$ and $q(t,x,s,y)$ to define two probability measures on the same metric space.

I have been attracted to the dual form of the Wasserstein distance, which for $p$ and $q$ above I would write like this. Using the $p=1$ form of Wasserstein distance in fine for my application, I believe.

$$W_1(p,q)= \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left[ \int f(x) d p(x) - \int f(x) d q(x) \right]$$

Where $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of all continuous functions with Lipschitz constant less than or equal to 1. For any function $f \in \mathcal{F}$, then this previous equation is equivalent to writing the following.

$$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p} [f(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{y \sim q} [f(y)] \le W_1(p,q)$$

This is pretty much as far as I have got. Is the way I've written this allowed, OK? What I am not super satisfied with is the transition from the expression of the transition density which is a function of 4 variables to the more general form of a probability measure that is contained in the definitions for the Wasserstein distance.

Is there a way to write the Wasserstein distance between $p$ and $q$ which includes all 4 space/time variables, $t, x, s, y$?